# Function Declaration in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

The following is one way to declare a function I guess(correct me) & I want to do something similar using same style but it's not working, why?

```
fun length nil = 0
| length (_::l') = 1 + (length l')
```

I want to do this without using "case expression of" syntax. i.e if function x get a number 3 then return 0 else if it's 4 then 1

```
fun x 3 = 0
| x (4) = 1

Here's the error
stdIn:58.5-59.12 Warning: match nonexhaustive
    3 => ...
    4 => ...
```

Q2) Also, where does the body of function start? it looks like nil is a parameter but then we have | so i'm confused!

Comment: What is the problem with the definition you posted? (Read about pattern matching in whatever book you're using.)

Comment: It's just a simple example for recursion. this
function has type 'a list -> int. That's all is written about it.

Comment: I mean your function. You say "it's not working" - what's wrong with it?

Comment: sorry i think it's working. just gives that warning i showed up there.

Comment: thanks though. I don't know why i didn't see that earlier.

Comment: How about Q2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a definition with pattern matching, and it means the same as

```
fun length ls = case ls of
                    nil => 0
                  | _::l' => 1 + (length l')
```

but is more concise and readable.

You get a warning on your function because you're only matching `3` and `4` but no other integers.

You will get the same warning if you write

```
fun x n = case n of
              3 => 0
            | 4 => 1
```

Matching all possible values would get rid of the warning:

```
fun x 3 = 0
  | x 4 = 1
  | x _ = 2
```